# How to set null values in SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
void main() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setString('key', null); // Error
}
```

How can I set a `null` value in [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

---

**Note:** I'm not looking for workarounds like, instead of `null`, use an empty string `''` and then check for it.

Comment: remove that key and later `getString` call will return `null`

Comment: @pskink To be able to show a min reproducible code, I am setting `key` to `null`, but in real world, I'm setting it somewhere else, and I am aware that the first time accessing the value, it's going to return `null`.

Comment: you simply cannot pass null - passing null would mean "there is no value with that key" - so instead just remove the item with that key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared preferences uses key value pairs to store data. Values can be of type int, double, string or bool. Afaik, null value is not supported.

For your purposes I would therefore suggest that if the value of the string you want to save is null, you remove any previous stored version of it from shared preferences. You can then detect the null by the absence of that key.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Thanks

Comment: `value == null ? prefs.remove('key') : prefs.setString('key', value);`

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the relevant entry using `await prefs.remove('key')`. That way when you call `prefs.getString('key')` you will get back `null`.

Comment: Other answer already mentioned this.